# overriding a value on a jquery post to a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

I have a "save" button and a "remove" button. If the user edits an account and saves, we assume the account is active, and therefore a value of 1 ("True") is preserved. If he/she clicks on the "Remove" button, then they are saving the same data, except that the account is no longer active, therefore we should save a 0 instead ("False"). How can I change the status of the account in case the user decides to go on with the "remove" action? I tried setting .val() for "IsActive" to .val('False') so it could be evaluated and turned into a 0 in Convert.ToBoolean but the application froze.

Here is my jquery post for the remove action:

```
 $("#RemoveAccount").click(function(e){


        $('#Display').show();
        $('#Display2').show();

        $.post("/RxCard/SaveAccount",
     {
         IsActive: $("#chkIsActive").val('False'),
         AccountId: $("#AccountID").val(),
         AccountName: $("#txtAccountName").val(),
         Address: $("#txtAddress").val(),
         City: $("#txtCity").val(),
         State: $("#txtState").val(),
         ZipCode: $("#txtZip").val(),
         Area: $("#txtArea").val(),
         Prefix: $("#txtPrefix").val(),
         Suffix: $("#txtSuffix").val()


     }).done(function (output) {
         if (output.length > 0)
             alert(output)
     }).always(function () {
         $("body").css("cursor", "default").delay(1000);
         // loadAccount(accountId);
     });     
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
[ValidateRequest]
[HttpPost]
public string SaveAccount(FormCollection form)
{
    Pharmacy pharmacy = new Pharmacy();
    var isactive = Convert.ToBoolean(form["IsActive"])?1:0;
    int AccountID = Convert.ToInt32(form["AccountId"]);
    var AccountName = form["AccountName"];
    var Address = form["Address"];
    var City = form["City"];
    var State = form["State"];
    var ZipCode = form["ZipCode"];
    var PhoneNumber = "(" + form["Area"] + ") " + form["Prefix"] + "-" + form["Suffix"];


    using (OdbcConnection _conn = new OdbcConnection("FILEDSN=c:\\datasources\\RxCard.dsn"))
    using (OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        cmd1.Connection = _conn;
        cmd1.CommandText = "{call web.Maint_UpdateClinic(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", AccountID);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isactive);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", AccountName);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", ZipCode);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WebID", CookieStore.GetCookie("WebId"));

        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _conn.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _conn.Close();
    }
    //Response.Redirect("~/rxcard/search");
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have two separate click handlers for "RemoveAccount" and "SaveAccount", why don't you set "IsActive" directly

```
$("#RemoveAccount").click(function(e){


    $('#Display').show();
    $('#Display2').show();

    $.post("/RxCard/SaveAccount",
 {
     IsActive: false, //for save account IsActive : true
     AccountId: $("#AccountID").val(),
     AccountName: $("#txtAccountName").val(),
     Address: $("#txtAddress").val(),
     City: $("#txtCity").val(),
     State: $("#txtState").val(),
     ZipCode: $("#txtZip").val(),
     Area: $("#txtArea").val(),
     Prefix: $("#txtPrefix").val(),
     Suffix: $("#txtSuffix").val()


 }).done(function (output) {
     if (output.length > 0)
         alert(output)
 }).always(function () {
     $("body").css("cursor", "default").delay(1000);
     // loadAccount(accountId);
 });
```

});

Comment: because I didn't think to do that. This worked perfectly! Thank you mr. @Paresh.